# Can Minimize work faster and/or be parallelized?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Having executed

```
Minimize[{y^2*z^2/(x*(y^2 + z^2)) + x^2*z^2/(y*(x^2 + z^2)) + y^2*x^2/(z*(x^2 + y^2)), 
1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {x, y, z}] // Timing
```

on my home comp with an antiquarian processor having two core, I obtained

> {8859.53, {(3 Sqrt[3])/
>     2, {x -> Root[{-27 + 4 #1^2 &, 
>         27 + 8 #1 #2 + 36 #2^2 + 8 #1 #2^3 - 142 #2^4 - 8 #1 #2^5 + 
>           100 #2^6 - 8 #1 #2^7 - 5 #2^8 &}, {2, 4}], 
>      y -> Root[{-27 + 4 #1^2 &, 
>         27 + 8 #1 #2 + 36 #2^2 + 8 #1 #2^3 - 142 #2^4 - 8 #1 #2^5 + 
>           100 #2^6 - 8 #1 #2^7 - 5 #2^8 &, -27 #2^4 - 8 #1 #2^5 + 
>           50 #2^6 + 8 #1 #2^7 - 27 #2^8 - 8 #1 #2^4 #3 - 8 #2^5 #3 + 
>           16 #1 #2^6 #3 + 8 #2^7 #3 - 8 #1 #2^8 #3 - 54 #2^2 #3^2 - 
>           16 #1 #2^3 #3^2 + 146 #2^4 #3^2 + 32 #1 #2^5 #3^2 - 
>           138 #2^6 #3^2 - 16 #1 #2^7 #3^2 + 46 #2^8 #3^2 - 
>           16 #1 #2^2 #3^3 - 16 #2^3 #3^3 + 40 #1 #2^4 #3^3 + 
>           24 #2^5 #3^3 - 32 #1 #2^6 #3^3 - 8 #2^7 #3^3 + 
>           8 #1 #2^8 #3^3 - 27 #3^4 - 8 #1 #2 #3^4 + 146 #2^2 #3^4 + 
>           40 #1 #2^3 #3^4 - 218 #2^4 #3^4 - 40 #1 #2^5 #3^4 + 
>           122 #2^6 #3^4 + 8 #1 #2^7 #3^4 - 15 #2^8 #3^4 - 8 #1 #3^5 - 
>           8 #2 #3^5 + 32 #1 #2^2 #3^5 + 24 #2^3 #3^5 - 
>           40 #1 #2^4 #3^5 - 16 #2^5 #3^5 + 16 #1 #2^6 #3^5 + 50 #3^6 + 
>           16 #1 #2 #3^6 - 138 #2^2 #3^6 - 32 #1 #2^3 #3^6 + 
>           122 #2^4 #3^6 + 16 #1 #2^5 #3^6 - 22 #2^6 #3^6 - 
>           12 #2^8 #3^6 + 8 #1 #3^7 + 8 #2 #3^7 - 16 #1 #2^2 #3^7 - 
>           8 #2^3 #3^7 + 8 #1 #2^4 #3^7 - 27 #3^8 - 8 #1 #2 #3^8 + 
>           46 #2^2 #3^8 + 8 #1 #2^3 #3^8 - 15 #2^4 #3^8 - 12 #2^6 #3^8 + 
>           4 #2^8 #3^8 &}, {2, 4, 4}], 
>      z -> Root[{-27 + 4 #1^2 &, 
>         27 + 8 #1 #2 + 36 #2^2 + 8 #1 #2^3 - 142 #2^4 - 8 #1 #2^5 + 
>           100 #2^6 - 8 #1 #2^7 - 5 #2^8 &, -27 #2^4 - 8 #1 #2^5 + 
>           50 #2^6 + 8 #1 #2^7 - 27 #2^8 - 8 #1 #2^4 #3 - 8 #2^5 #3 + 
>           16 #1 #2^6 #3 + 8 #2^7 #3 - 8 #1 #2^8 #3 - 54 #2^2 #3^2 - 
>           16 #1 #2^3 #3^2 + 146 #2^4 #3^2 + 32 #1 #2^5 #3^2 - 
>           138 #2^6 #3^2 - 16 #1 #2^7 #3^2 + 46 #2^8 #3^2 - 
>           16 #1 #2^2 #3^3 - 16 #2^3 #3^3 + 40 #1 #2^4 #3^3 + 
>           24 #2^5 #3^3 - 32 #1 #2^6 #3^3 - 8 #2^7 #3^3 + 
>           8 #1 #2^8 #3^3 - 27 #3^4 - 8 #1 #2 #3^4 + 146 #2^2 #3^4 + 
>           40 #1 #2^3 #3^4 - 218 #2^4 #3^4 - 40 #1 #2^5 #3^4 + 
>           122 #2^6 #3^4 + 8 #1 #2^7 #3^4 - 15 #2^8 #3^4 - 8 #1 #3^5 - 
>           8 #2 #3^5 + 32 #1 #2^2 #3^5 + 24 #2^3 #3^5 - 
>           40 #1 #2^4 #3^5 - 16 #2^5 #3^5 + 16 #1 #2^6 #3^5 + 50 #3^6 + 
>           16 #1 #2 #3^6 - 138 #2^2 #3^6 - 32 #1 #2^3 #3^6 + 
>           122 #2^4 #3^6 + 16 #1 #2^5 #3^6 - 22 #2^6 #3^6 - 
>           12 #2^8 #3^6 + 8 #1 #3^7 + 8 #2 #3^7 - 16 #1 #2^2 #3^7 - 
>           8 #2^3 #3^7 + 8 #1 #2^4 #3^7 - 27 #3^8 - 8 #1 #2 #3^8 + 
>           46 #2^2 #3^8 + 8 #1 #2^3 #3^8 - 15 #2^4 #3^8 - 12 #2^6 #3^8 + 
>           4 #2^8 #3^8 &, -#2^2 #3^2 - #2^2 #4^2 - #3^2 #4^2 + #2^2 #3^2 #4^2 &}, {2, 4, 4, 2}]}}}

The above result is a serious achievement of Mathematica 11. I dislike only 8859.53 seconds. Because the execution takes less than 100MB of RAM, the question arises: can it be done faster?

Comment: Typically symbolic minimization involves recursive algorithms that are hard to modify to run in parallel so, as far as I know, `Minimize` won't naturally operate in parallel. There are other, numerical algorithms that can be run in parallel though; see [ParallelEvaluatefor function minimization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32438).

Comment: @MarcoB : Thank you. The linked discussion is from 2013 and times change. The point is to obtain an exact result in a faster way. BTW, Maple uses about 1 GB, solving this, and produces a numerical answer in few minutes.

Comment: From the title of the discussion and the question formulation it is not clear are you asking for (1) a faster way to do the described computation, or (2) how to do parallel computations set-up for `Minimize`.

Comment: @Anton Antonov : Thank you for your interest. I am more interested in (1), but (2) also is  of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is as follows.  First, `Minimize` the function and constraint over `{x, y}`, treating `z` for now as a free parameter.

```
Minimize[{y^2*z^2/(x*(y^2 + z^2)) + x^2*z^2/(y*(x^2 + z^2)) + y^2*x^2/(z*(x^2 + y^2)), 
    1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {x, y}];
```

and then `Minimize` its result (which is a bit long to reproduce here) with respect to `z`.

```
Minimize[First[%], z]
(* {(3 Sqrt[3])/2, {z -> Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

which yields the minimum and corresponding value of `z`.  The corresponding values of `x` and `y` are readily obtained from

```
Minimize[{y^2*z^2/(x*(y^2 + z^2)) + x^2*z^2/(y*(x^2 + z^2)) + y^2*x^2/(z*(x^2 + y^2)), 
   1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0} /. Last[%], {x, y}] // RootReduce
(* {(3 Sqrt[3])/2, {x -> Sqrt[3], y -> Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

This entire calculation takes about ten seconds on my computer.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you, @bbgodfrey. The above is simple and strong. That approach works in higher dimensions too. I accept it. The question about  the parallelization remains open.

Answer (score 5):

A plot the function to be minimized on the surface defined by the constraint shows that the extremum lies at `x == y == z`.

```
ContourPlot3D[1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2 == 1, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, , Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {5, 5, 5}}}
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, 
    y^2*z^2/(x*(y^2 + z^2)) + x^2*z^2/(y*(x^2 + z^2)) + y^2*x^2/(z*(x^2 + y^2))]}]
```

[image]

(The observation that the function to be minimized, as well as the constraint, are invariant under interchanges among `{x, y, z}` also supports the prediction that the extremum lies at `x == y == z`.)  With this simplification, the function and constraint become

```
{y^2*z^2/(x*(y^2 + z^2)) + x^2*z^2/(y*(x^2 + z^2)) + y^2*x^2/(z*(x^2 + y^2)), 
 1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2 == 1} /. {z -> x, y -> x}

(* {(3 x)/2, 3/x^2 == 1} *)
```

Thus, `x == y  == z == Sqrt[3]`, yielding an extremum of `3 Sqrt[3]/2`, as in the question.  Moreover, applying `RootReduce` to that lengthy result yields in just a few seconds

```
{* {(3 Sqrt[3])/2, {x -> Sqrt[3], y -> Sqrt[3], z -> Sqrt[3]}} *}
```

in agreement with the result obtained here.  The approach presented here takes less than a minute instead of a few hours of computer time.

Comment: Sorry, but a plot is not any serious argument. I can't accept your attempt in the present form. I wonder the upvotes.

Comment: @user64494  The plot shows not so much that the minimum is at `x == y == z` as that there is only one minimum.  That fact in turn implies that the minimum must be at `x == y == z`.  To explore this more carefully, reduce the plot range toward the minimum to see that there is only one there.  You also could expand the function about this point to demonstrate that it is at least a local minimum.

Comment: Sorry, but I have nothing to discuss with you in such style.

Comment: Umm, user64494, that's just a display of bad manners. Possibly also bad math, unless one is a huge fan of the Bourbaki school/style.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: I prefer based arguments over emotional words

Comment: Ah yes, I had underestimated the raw emotion bared by that beige-to-brown contour plot. Doubtless the blue/green range would have made a calmer appeal to reason..